# mysql conditional field update

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, case

I have 3 columns in CATEGORY TABLE for storing pre-calculated counts of records for it in another table PRODUCTS.

```
CATEGORY(c_id,name,c30,c31,c32)
```

c30=count for New Products (value 30)
c31 count for used products  (value 31)
c32 count for Damaged products  (value 32)

```
PRODUCT(p_id,c_id,name,condition)
```

condition can be 30,31 or 32.

I am thinking to write a single UPDATE statement so, it will update respective category count.

Althogh below statement is syntactically wrong, but i am looking for similar type of solution.

```
select case product.condition 
when 30 then update category set category.c30=category.c30+1 where category.c_id=product.category3
when 31 then update category set category.c31=category.c31+1 where category.c_id=product.category3
when 32 then update category set category.c32=category.c32+1 where category.c_id=product.category3
end case
from product 
where product.c_id=12
```

Any suggestion!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
UPDATE CATEGORY c
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT 
      c_id,
      SUM(CASE WHEN `condition` = 30 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) c30,
      SUM(CASE WHEN `condition` = 31 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) c31,
      SUM(CASE WHEN `condition` = 32 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) c32
    FROM product
    GROUP BY c_id
) p ON c.c_id = p.c_id
SET c.c30 = p.c30, 
    c.c31 = p.c31,
    c.c32 = p.c32;
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ce028/1)

Comment: @Mahmoud Gamal, quick and good, i saw your answer at the same time, but it takes 1 day in execution and validating your answer. and now i can sy its perfect. Solution performance is also quick, Query took 0.4998 sec on a huge table with more than 2 lac records Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can join both the tables and then update the value in same join query.